# How to assign jobs to a ship as a many-to-many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a shipping project where I can create ships and jobs. I have a many-to-many relationship with jobs and ships, but I'm having trouble creating new jobs for a ship.

I want a new link to assign jobs for a specific boat via check-boxes but I get an error when I click on the link to assign jobs when no route matches `get "/ship/all_jobs"`.

This is my Ship model:

```
class Ship < ApplicationRecord

  has_and_belongs_to_many :jobs

  has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100#" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

  validates :name, uniqueness: true

end
```

This is my Job model:

```
class Job < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :ships

  validate :price_has_to_be_greater_than_minimum
  validates :title, uniqueness: true
  validates :description, length: { minimum: 50 }

  def price_has_to_be_greater_than_minimum
    errors.add(:cost, "price has to be greater than 1000") if
    !cost.blank? and cost > 1000
  end
end
```

This is the Jobship join table:

```
class Jobship < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :ships
  belongs_to :jobs
end
```

and my ships controller:

```
def all_jobs
  @ship = Ship.find(params[:id])
end

def create
  @ship = Ship.new(ship_params)
  if @ship.save
    flash[:notice] = 'Ship record was successfully created.'
    redirect_to(@ship)
  else
    render :action => "new"
  end
end

def save
  @ship = Ship.find(params[:id])
  @job = Job.find(params[:job])
  if params[:show] == "true"
    @ship.jobs << @ship
  else
    @ship.jobs.delete(@ship)
  end
  @ship.save!
  render :nothing => true
end

private

def ship_params
  params.require(:ship).permit(:name, :location, :avatar)
end
end
```

This is the all_jobs view:

```
<h1>jobs for <%= @ship.name %></h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>assignl</th>
    <th>job</th>
  </tr>


  <%= form_for (@ship) do |f| %>
    <%= f.label "jobs" %><br />
    <%= f.collection_check_boxes :job_ids, Job.all, :id, :title do |b| %>
      <div class="collection-check-box">
        <%= b.check_box %>
        <%= b.label %>


       <%= f.submit %>
    <%end%>
  <%end%>
```

This is the link to all jobs from the index view:

```
<%= link_to 'New ship', new_ship_path %>
<% @ships.each do |ship| %>
  <h1>ship name</h1><%=ship.name%><h1> ship location</h1>   <%= ship.location %>    <%= link_to 'Show', ship %>

  <%= link_to 'jobs',   ship_all_jobs_path(ship) %>
  <%= link_to "all jobs", jobs_path %>
<% end %>
```

And my routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users
  resources :ships
  resources :jobs

  root :to => "ships#index"

  post "ship/all_jobs", :to=> "ships#save"

  get "ship/all_jobs/:id", :to => "ships#all_jobs"
end
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please be more aware of appropriate formatting and your grammar. Stack Overflow isn't a discussion list, instead it's an online reference book where spelling and grammar matter. Using your browser's spell-check will help a lot. "[How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)" has some good tips for working with a site and community such as this.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are going all  wrong about `many to many` relationships in rails, you don't need separate model for the join table, active record takes care of it read here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association to learn more; so you don't need the `Jobship` model.

```
class Jobship < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :ships
  belongs_to :jobs
end
```

You have to put `/` before you define your routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users
  resources :ships
  resources :jobs

  root :to => "ships#index"

  post "/ship/all_jobs", :to=> "ships#save"

  get "/ship/all_jobs/:id", :to => "ships#all_jobs"
end
```

also you can see your defined routes using `rails routes` in the command line.